# Wrong symbols beside badges

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog

While I was on Music meta recently, a +5 popped into my achievements box.  I clicked on my notification box, and this is what I saw:

[image]

Notice that the badge I got on Literature.SE has a "Note" badge beside it.  Shouldn't it be the generic dot, even though I am on the Music stack?

Comment: The badge icon is fetched from the local site.